# NPM: Unmet dependencies on Debian 9.13 Stretch

Tags: debian, npm

I'm trying to install NPM on a Google Cloud Platform Debian Instance running Debian 9.13 Stretch. However, if I try to use `$ sudo apt install npm` I get the following message

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                        
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                             
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                    
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have                                                                                                                    
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable                                                                                                                   
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created                                                                                                                   
or been moved out of Incoming.                                                                                                                                                       
The following information may help to resolve the situation:                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                     
The following packages have unmet dependencies:                                                                                                                                      
 npm : Depends: nodejs (>= 6.11~) but 4.8.2~dfsg-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.1.1~) but 1.0.9-1 is to be installed                                                                                                               
       Depends: node-ansi-regex (>= 3.0~) but 2.0.0-1 is to be installed                                                                                                             
       Depends: node-cacache (>= 10.0.4~) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                        
       Depends: node-config-chain (>= 1.1.11~) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                   
       Depends: node-glob (>= 7.1.2~) but 7.1.1-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                 
       Depends: node-hosted-git-info (>= 2.6~) but 2.1.5-1 is to be installed                                                                                                        
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.3.5~) but 1.1.0-1+deb9u1 is to be installed                                                                                                           
       Depends: node-npm-package-arg but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                             
       Depends: node-jsonstream (>= 1.3.2~) but 1.0.3-4 is to be installed                                                                                                           
       Depends: node-libnpx (>= 10.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                         
       Depends: node-lockfile (>= 1.0.3~) but 0.4.1-1 is to be installed                                                                                                             
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 4.1.1~) but 4.0.2-1 is to be installed                                                                                                            
       Depends: node-move-concurrently (>= 1.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                               
       Depends: node-normalize-package-data (>= 2.4~) but 2.3.5-2 is to be installed                                                                                                 
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) but 3.4.0-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                  
       Depends: node-resolve-from (>= 4.0~) but 2.0.0-1 is to be installed                                                                                                           
       Depends: node-npmlog (>= 4.1.2~) but 0.0.4-1 is to be installed                                                                                                               
       Depends: node-osenv (>= 0.1.5~) but 0.1.0-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 2.0.13~) but 1.2.4-1 is to be installed                                                                                                   
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.83~) but 2.26.1-1 is to be installed                                                                                                              
       Depends: node-retry (>= 0.10.1~) but 0.6.0-1 is to be installed                                                                                                               
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.6.2~) but 2.5.4-2 is to be installed                                                                                                               
       Depends: node-semver (>= 5.5~) but 5.3.0-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                 
       Depends: node-sha (>= 2.0.1~) but 1.2.3-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                  
       Depends: node-slide (>= 1.1.6~) but 1.1.4-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                
       Depends: node-strip-ansi (>= 4.0~) but 3.0.1-1 is to be installed                                                                                                             
       Depends: node-tar (>= 4.4~) but 2.2.1-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                    
       Depends: node-boxen (>= 1.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                           
       Depends: node-latest-version (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed                                                                                                    
       Depends: node-which (>= 1.3~) but 1.2.11-1 is to be installed                                                                                                                 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm using the default sources list, and have tried `$sudo apt install -f npm` and have also tried several times to run `sudo apt update` and standard commands to find the issue. Any ideas? Can't find a bug report for this either.

edit: the output of `sudo apt-cache policy npm`

```
\npm:                                                                                                                                                                                
  Installed: (none)                                                                                                                                                                  
  Candidate: 5.8.0+ds6-2~bpo9+1                                                                                                                                                      
  Version table:                                                                                                                                                                     
     5.8.0+ds6-2~bpo9+1 100                                                                                                                                                          
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 4):

`npm` is in the somewhat unusual situation of only being available in Stretch backports, not the main Debian 9 repositories, while also requiring other packages from backports. Because the latter aren’t installation candidates by default, you need to tell `apt` to consider them:

```
sudo apt install -t stretch-backports npm
```

Answer (score 2):

node is available [as a `snap`](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#snap):

```
sudo apt install snapd 
sudo snap refresh node --channel=15
sudo snap install node --classic --channel=15
```

And also has a separate repository; using the [installation script](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```